# ¿Mejor TAD para contar datos repetidos?

Tags: estructuras-de-datos

Tengo un registro de actores que muestra que personajes representaron en las películas que aparecen siguiendo este estilo csv:

```
imdb_title_id,ordering,imdb_name_id,category,job,characters
tt0000009,1,nm0063086,actress,,"[""Miss Geraldine Holbrook (Miss Jerry)""]"
```

imdb_title_ id = película en la que actuaron

imdb_name_id = código único a cada actor

La pregunta es, ¿Que TAD debería usar para encontrar que actor fue el que tuvo más apariciones? Tener en cuenta que un actor puede tener personajes en diferentes películas y que cada película cuenta como una aparición.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué es un TAD?

Comment: @MauricioContreras, un TAD es un tipo abstracto de datos, es decir, una lista enlazada, una árbol binario, un heap, un hash,etc. Intente utilizar un hasheo por el codigo del actor, el problema es que otro código podría tener el hasheo que otro codigo de actor diferente, por lo tanto, estaría mezclando datos de otros actores.

Comment: Un hash de [SHA-256](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) te permite un rango bastante alto de posibilidades como para que se produzcan colisiones sobre el conjunto de datos que manejas. ¿Qué tipo de *hash* has intentado usar como para que se produzcan colisiones? En todo caso, tu pregunta parece basada en opiniones. Te sugiero leer [ask] y lo que dice el [help/dont-ask] sobre el tipo de preguntas que debemos evitar en el sitio. Saludos